# Passing variable through 3 pages - PHP

Tags: php, forms, session, get, parameter-passing

so i have a form at sampleform.html which accepts user's value [This is a number chosen from a dropdown menu. The number is the id of a ward]

This number is passed onto index.php through the GET method. Now, on index.php, the user sees details related to the number he chose (from a mysql database) and he has two links to choose from:

1. Lorry routes
2. Tricycle routes

I want to pass a new variable 'route=lor' or 'route=tri' through a hyperlink url and also the original ward number from sampleform.html to a new page - route.php through index.php

I tried $_SESSION on index.php, where $_SESSION['wardno'] accepts the $_GET['wno'] value from sampleform.html. But I'm not able to see any output on route.php when i call $_SESSION['wardno'].

How do i pass this variable from sampleform.html, through index.php and to route.php after clicking on one of the two hyperlinks on index.php??

I'm seeing no syntax errors. Will put up the code if you guys don't understand the question.

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Kaushik

Comment: Do you start the session on the pages that you are trying to manipulate $_SESSION data with?

Comment: yes i did. Sampleform.html only accepts the user value. I've called session_start(); on both index.php and route.php

Comment: If you could post the code that isn't working it might be easier to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the names and values of whatever GET query variables you want to pass on through index.php in the `href` attributes of the two hyperlinks.

---

Code snippet #1

```
<?php
    function getparams() {
        foreach ($_GET as $k => $v)
            $r .= htmlspecialchars(urlencode($k)) . '=' .
                  htmlspecialchars(urlencode($v)) . '&';
        return $r;
    }
?>
<a href="route.php?route=lor&<?php echo getparams(); ?>">link 1</a>
<a href="route.php?route=tri&<?php echo getparams(); ?>">link 2</a>
```

Comment: can you give me an example code? How do you pass it? I tried this: 

`echo '<a href="http://www.letsrob.org/trashvigil/route.php?route=lor&wardno='$wno'">Lorry routes</a></br>';`

I know the syntax is wrong cause that gives me an error

Comment: See "Code snippet #1" in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. It did help, in the sense that I simply didn't think of opening a php tag within href, to print the value. That's what I've done now and it works. But I don't quite understand your function. If you can elaborate?

Comment: Also, isn't there a way to do this with $_SESSION??

Comment: The function constructs a query string fragment with all the GET variables that the page received, so that they can be passed on to the next page. Yes, you can use a session, but that isn't quite as good, because for example, if the user has two tabs and going through the pages separately, they can't with the session method.

Comment: Okay awesome!

Now my question is, is the function a necessity? As in, I'm passing only an integer data. But does the function play a role in security or something?

Comment: You need it, because technically you don't control what comes into index.php; some malicious user could feed HTML directly into index.php's output just by putting HTML in the query.